# React Router Dom Pathname keeps nesting

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a React app in which a search options is included in the navbar, and can be accessed anywhere in the app. Whenever a user searches and then clicks on one of the products show, it should send them to a detail view of that product.

The problem I am facing is with routing. Whenever I search and click in the product for the first time, it correctly redirects to, as an example, `http://localhost:3000/catalogue/women/sportive-shoes-sneakers/sneakers--low-top-sneaker/292487`. However, if once I am in that route I try to go send the user to another product, it formulates the url like this: `http://localhost:3000/catalogue/women/sportive-shoes-sneakers/sneakers--low-top-sneaker/catalogue/men/denim-pants/jeans/293140`. As you can see, it's nesting the pathnames one after the other.

My code looks like this:

```js
this.state.displayProducts.map((product, index) => {
    return (
        <NavLink strict to={{
            pathname: `catalogue/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.line)}/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.familyName)}/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.subfamilyName)}/${product.id[0] || product.id}`,
            selectedProduct: product
        }} key={index}>
            <div className="catalogue-productlist-product" onClick={this.props.wipeInput && this.props.wipeInput}>
                <img src={product.images && product.images[0] ? product.images[0].replace('{authorization}', this.props.token) : this.props.placeholder}
                    alt="Category" onError={this.imgError} />
                <div>
                    {product.productName}
                </div>
            </div>
        </NavLink>
    )
})
```

And my Route like this:

```js
<Route
    exact path="/catalogue"
    render={(props) => (
        window.location.search.length > 0 ?
            <ProductList />
            :
            <Slider
                {...props}
                categories={this.props.categories}
            />
    )}
/>

<Route
    exact path={`/catalogue/search/:qs`}
    component={ProductList}
/>

<Route
    exact path={`/catalogue/:line/:family?/`}
    render={(props) => (
        <Slider
            {...props}
            categories={this.props.categories}
        />
    )} />

<Route
    exact path={`/catalogue/:line/:family/:subfamily`}
    component={ProductList} />

<Route
    exact path={`/catalogue/:line/:family/:subfamily/:product`}
    component={ProductDetail} />
```

How would one go about it working as intended? ie: no matter the current route, the user should always be sent to wherever the navlink send them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here in your pathname, you should always consider add a **leading slash in your pathnames** just like this:

```js
...
pathname: `/catalogue/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.line)}/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.familyName)}/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.subfamilyName)}/${product.id[0] || product.id}`
...
```

If you don't use this leading slash in your link navigation **it will always append the path you provided to the previous path that you provided**, so it will make your first redirect nice and tidy then the upcoming ones will append to the existing path that you are in right now.

**NOTE:** If you always want to change the whole directory with each product selected consider adding leading slash in your pathname, otherwise, you should use an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what the problem is, I am not 100% sure but going to go out on a limb, because I have encountered similar issues in the past, I think you need to add a `'/'` to the pathname value before 'catalogue'.

```js
...
                                    return (
                                        <NavLink strict to={{
                                            pathname: `/catalogue/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.line)}/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.familyName)}/${StringUtil.getUrlFromString(product.subfamilyName)}/${product.id[0] || product.id}`,
...
```

Because it is not prefixed with '/', it is appending the path to the current path rather than starting it from the beginning.